# I want to display specific contents from JSON object into a table structure? how can i do that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

```
{"symbol":"DRREDDY","series":"EQ","openPrice":"3,132.00","highPrice":"3,229.90","lowPrice":"3,132.00","ltp":"3,206.35","previousPrice":"3,153.25","netPrice":"1.68","tradedQuantity":"74,165","turnoverInLakhs":"2,379.33","lastCorpAnnouncementDate":"18-Jul-2016","lastCorpAnnouncement":"Annual General Meeting\/ Dividend - Rs 20\/- PerShare"},{"symbol":"ACC","series":"EQ","openPrice":"1,567.00","highPrice":"1,606.85","lowPrice":"1,564.85","ltp":"1,594.25","previousPrice":"1,568.10","netPrice":"1.67","tradedQuantity":"1,03,292","turnoverInLakhs":"1,645.62","lastCorpAnnouncementDate":"22-Feb-2016","lastCorpAnnouncement":"Dividend - Rs 6\/- Per Share"},
{"symbol":"ACC","series":"EQ","openPrice":"1,567.00","highPrice":"1,606.85","lowPrice":"1,564.85","ltp":"1,594.25","previousPrice":"1,568.10","netPrice":"1.67","tradedQuantity":"1,03,292","turnoverInLakhs":"1,645.62","lastCorpAnnouncementDate":"22-Feb-2016","lastCorpAnnouncement":"Dividend - Rs 6\/- Per Share"}
```

This is the JSON object.I want to store all the symbol names, high price and low price in separate variables and display those alone in my page in table structure with symbol, high price and low price as columns? How can i do that ? Am able to acces one symbol at a time but i want all the symbols to b displayed ?

Comment: That is not a JSON object. [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) contains only a couple of methods, nothing interesting to show on a page.

Comment: It will be list of JSON objects right?

Comment: My task is to print the symbol names, high and low prices which is given in a text file separately i parsed the text file as a json object so now i want to display it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = [{
    "symbol":"DRREDDY",
    "series":"EQ",
    "openPrice":"3,132.00",
    "highPrice":"3,229.90",
    "lowPrice":"3,132.00",
    "ltp":"3,206.35",
    "previousPrice":"3,153.25",
    "netPrice":"1.68",
    "tradedQuantity":"74,165",
    "turnoverInLakhs":"2,379.33",
    "lastCorpAnnouncementDate":"18-Jul-2016",
    "lastCorpAnnouncement":"Annual General Meeting\/ Dividend - Rs 20\/- PerShare"
    },
    ...
];

var table = $('<table>');
table.append('<thead><tr><td>symbol</td><td>highPrice</td><td>lowPrice</td></tr></thead>');
for(var i in data){
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    var td1 = '<td>' + data[i].symbol;
    var td2 = '<td>' + data[i].highPrice;
    var td3 = '<td>' + data[i].lowPrice;
    tr.append(td1,td2,td3);
    table.append(tr);
}

$('#your-panel').append(table);
```

[There is Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MoHSenMHS/Lw3nfbj6/1/)

Comment: what is #your-panel ??

Comment: `div` or any section that you want to add your table to that, i mention it by `id="your-panel". @Karthikeyan_kk

Comment: all works perfect i added this code to a button whenever i click that function table of contents is repeatedly printing how to stop that

Comment: I update my fiddle, you can see that. [see this link](https://jsfiddle.net/MoHSenMHS/Lw3nfbj6/2/) @Karthikeyan_kk

Comment: Thanks for the update what am trying to ask is whenever i press add table button the table keeps on adding right. In my case i have two buttons both shows different tables so after pressing the button once if i press that button again it should not print the table again what should i do for that??

Comment: like i pressed button 1 and table 1 is printed then i pressed button 2 table 2 is printed now if i press button 1 again its showing table 1 twice i want it only once

Comment: You can use `$('#your-panel').html(table)` against `$('#your-panel').append(table)`, i update fiddle. @Karthikeyan_kk

Answer (score 0):

assuming your objects exist in an array like below

```
var arr = [{
    "symbol":"DRREDDY",
    "series":"EQ",
    "openPrice":"3,132.00",
    "highPrice":"3,229.90",
    "lowPrice":"3,132.00",
    "ltp":"3,206.35",
    "previousPrice":"3,153.25",
    "netPrice":"1.68",
    "tradedQuantity":"74,165",
    "turnoverInLakhs":"2,379.33",
    "lastCorpAnnouncementDate":"18-Jul-2016",
    "lastCorpAnnouncement":"Annual General Meeting\/ Dividend - Rs 20\/- PerShare"
},
{
    "symbol":"ACC",
    "series":"EQ",
    "openPrice":"1,567.00",
    "highPrice":"1,606.85",
    "lowPrice":"1,564.85",
    "ltp":"1,594.25",
    "previousPrice":"1,568.10",
    "netPrice":"1.67",
    "tradedQuantity":"1,03,292",
    "turnoverInLakhs":"1,645.62",
    "lastCorpAnnouncementDate":"22-Feb-2016",
    "lastCorpAnnouncement":"Dividend - Rs 6\/- Per Share"
},

{
    "symbol":"ACC",
    "series":"EQ",
    "openPrice":"1,567.00",
    "highPrice":"1,606.85",
    "lowPrice":"1,564.85",
    "ltp":"1,594.25",
    "previousPrice":"1,568.10",
    "netPrice":"1.67",
    "tradedQuantity":"1,03,292",
    "turnoverInLakhs":"1,645.62",
    "lastCorpAnnouncementDate":"22-Feb-2016",
    "lastCorpAnnouncement":"Dividend - Rs 6\/- Per Share"
}]
```

you can loop through array to draw rows
and loop through objects to draw columns like below

```
var tableData = ''
arr.map((x) => {
tableData += '<tr><td>' + x.highPrice + '</td><td>' + x.lowPrice + '</td></tr>';  
});
$('table').find('tbody').html(tableData)
```

Comment: please recheck my answer

Comment: Thankyou for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Iterate list to table

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
for(var i =0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell1.innerHTML =  data[i].symbol;
    cell2.innerHTML = data[i].highPrice;
    cell3.innerHTML = data[i].lowPrice;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scsiva1991/f9ueergk/)

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to create separate array for symbol, highPrice & lowPrice.

Instead you can use [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through the json array and get each of the item

```
var _tbody = $('tbody');
_myJson.forEach(function(item){
var _tr = '<tr><td>'+item.symbol+'</td><td>'+item.highPrice+'</td><td>'+item.lowPrice+'</td></tr>'
_tbody+=_tr
})
$('#demoTable').append(_tbody)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lw3nfbj6/)

Comment: your answer is working perfectly i kept all these functions inside a button called display table. if i press that button more than once table of contents is repeated how to stop that??

Answer (score 0):

consider

```
var result= {"symbol":"DRREDDY","series":"EQ","openPrice":"3,132.00","highPrice":"3,229.90","lowPrice":"3,132.00","ltp":"3,206.35","previousPrice":"3,153.25","netPrice":"1.68","tradedQuantity":"74,165","turnoverInLakhs":"2,379.33","lastCorpAnnouncementDate":"18-Jul-2016","lastCorpAnnouncement":"Annual General Meeting\/ Dividend - Rs 20\/- PerShare"},

{"symbol":"ACC","series":"EQ","openPrice":"1,567.00","highPrice":"1,606.85","lowPrice":"1,564.85","ltp":"1,594.25","previousPrice":"1,568.10","netPrice":"1.67","tradedQuantity":"1,03,292","turnoverInLakhs":"1,645.62","lastCorpAnnouncementDate":"22-Feb-2016","lastCorpAnnouncement":"Dividend - Rs 6\/- Per Share"},
{"symbol":"ACC","series":"EQ","openPrice":"1,567.00","highPrice":"1,606.85","lowPrice":"1,564.85","ltp":"1,594.25","previousPrice":"1,568.10","netPrice":"1.67","tradedQuantity":"1,03,292","turnoverInLakhs":"1,645.62","lastCorpAnnouncementDate":"22-Feb-2016","lastCorpAnnouncement":"Dividend - Rs 6\/- Per Share"}

var low_price,high_price,symbols=[];

for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
low_price[i]=result[i].lowPrice;
}
```

to display in table u can use a display function inside the for loop like this ..

```
for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
//low_price[i]=result[i].lowPrice;
display(result[i]);
}

function display(result){
var rows='<tr>'+
'<td>'+result.symbol+'</td>'+
'<td>'+result.highPrice+'</td>'+
'<td>'+result.lowPrice+'</td>'+
'</tr>';
$('#result').append(rows);

}
```

In html page

```
<div>
<table>
<thead>
<th>Symbols</th>
<th>High price</th>
<th>Low price</th>
</thead>
<tbody id="result">
// your display function will be add rows using append function ...
</tbody>
</table>
</div
```

i guess u r looking for this .. otherwise sorry for the wrong information

please provide more information that u want